# How to match the first occurrence of a pattern (or character) except for lines where that pattern is at the beginning of the line?

Tags: regex

I have the following example lines:

```
!foobar foo bar ! foo               ---> NO MATCH
foo bar foo bar !   foo             ---> Should match !
foo bar foo bar ! ! fooo bar !      ---> Should ONLY match the first ! 
! ! foo bar                         ---> NO MATCH
!foo bar foo bar ! ! fooo bar !     ---> NO MATCH
```

and I would like to find a regex expression that would match only the first occurrence of the character "!" except where the lines if the character is at the beginning of the line.
I have tried to no avail using many different combinations (maybe not properly) of negative lookback like `^(?!\!)\!`.

I'm planning to use this regex expression as an input for a command that needs forcefully a regex expression, hence I can't use other methods.

Comment: You may use `^.*?\K(?!^)!` or `^[^!\r\n]*\K(?!^)!` if you are using PCRE

Comment: If you need a helpful answer please explain what you are doing and using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex:

```
^[^!]+(!).*
```

Group 1 contains your match.

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/6KYWg8/1/).

Please note that this solution works only with single characters (in this case, `!`).